# SQLite Exception: no such column Constants.Column_Minute(code 1)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am getting an error that says my minute column does not exist even though I clearly have initialized it when creating my database table

this is my database activity where the problem is

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    String CREATE_ALARM_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME +
            " ( " + Constants.KEY_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + Constants.COLUMN_NAME +
            " TEXT, " + Constants.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " + Constants.COLUMN_HOUR +
            " INT, " + Constants.COLUMN_MINUTE + " INT, "+ Constants.COLUMN_YEAR +
            " INT, " + Constants.COLUMN_MONTH +
            " INT, " + Constants.COLUMN_DAY +
            " INT, " +Constants.COLUMN_TYPE+ " TEXT);";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_ALARM_DATABASE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + Constants.TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);

}


 public void addAlarms(MyAlarm alarm) {

     SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();


     ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
     values.put(Constants.COLUMN_NAME , alarm.getTitle());
     values.put(Constants.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION , alarm.getContent());
     values.put(Constants.COLUMN_HOUR , alarm.getHours());
     values.put(Constants.COLUMN_MINUTE , alarm.getMinutes());
     values.put(Constants.COLUMN_YEAR,alarm.getYear());
     values.put(Constants.COLUMN_MONTH,alarm.getMonth());
     values.put(Constants.COLUMN_DAY,alarm.getDay());
     values.put(Constants.COLUMN_TYPE, alarm.getType());

     db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
     db.close();
}

public ArrayList<MyAlarm> getAlarms(){

    String selectQuery= "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


    Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{Constants.KEY_ID, Constants.COLUMN_NAME
    ,Constants.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, Constants.COLUMN_MINUTE, Constants.COLUMN_HOUR, Constants.COLUMN_YEAR
            ,Constants.COLUMN_MONTH,Constants.COLUMN_DAY,Constants.COLUMN_TYPE},null,null,null,null,Constants.COLUMN_YEAR
    + " DESC");

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{

            MyAlarm alarm = new MyAlarm();
            alarm.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_NAME)));
            alarm.setContent(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)));

            alarm.setYear(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_YEAR)));
            alarm.setMonth(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_MONTH)));
            alarm.setDay(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_DAY)));
            alarm.setHours(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_HOUR)));
            alarm.setMinutes(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_MINUTE)));
            alarm.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID)));
            alarm.setType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_TYPE)));

            alarmList.add(alarm);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return alarmList;
}
```

the error always points to my cursor...any help would be much appreciated

EDIT:Logcat added

```
      05-20 00:53:45.977 13871-13871/seniorreminder.androidstudioprojects.com.seniorreminder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                     Process: seniorreminder.androidstudioprojects.com.seniorreminder, PID: 13871
                                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{seniorreminder.androidstudioprojects.com.seniorreminder/seniorreminder.androidstudioprojects.com.seniorreminder.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXIST": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXIST alarms
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                                      Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXIST": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXIST alarms
                                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
                                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
                                                                                                         at seniorreminder.androidstudioprojects.com.seniorreminder.Database.DatabaseActivity.onUpgrade(DatabaseActivity.java:45)
                                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)
                                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
                                                                                                         at seniorreminder.androidstudioprojects.com.seniorreminder.Database.DatabaseActivity.getAlarms(DatabaseActivity.java:74)
                                                                                                         at seniorreminder.androidstudioprojects.com.seniorreminder.MainActivity.refreshData(MainActivity.java:131)
                                                                                                         at seniorreminder.androidstudioprojects.com.seniorreminder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
                                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Comment: i just did @MikeT

Comment: **`SQLiteException: near "EXIST": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXIST alarms`**  Should be **EXISTS** (with an S at the end). i.e. `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + Constants.TABLE_NAME);` should be `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Constants.TABLE_NAME);`

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, with a few other suggestions. You can then accept the answer.

Comment: will do that@MikeT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error, according to the logcat, is **'SQLiteException: near "EXIST": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DROP TABLE IF EXIST alarms'**

The cause is that SQLite does not have a keyword called EXIST. The keyword should be **EXISTS**. So to fix this issue make the following change:-

Replace **`db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + Constants.TABLE_NAME);`** with

**`db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Constants.TABLE_NAME);`**

You may also wish to consider simplifying

`Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{Constants.KEY_ID, Constants.COLUMN_NAME
    ,Constants.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, Constants.COLUMN_MINUTE, Constants.COLUMN_HOUR, Constants.COLUMN_YEAR
            ,Constants.COLUMN_MONTH,Constants.COLUMN_DAY,Constants.COLUMN_TYPE},null,null,null,null,Constants.COLUMN_YEAR
    + " DESC");`

It could be

```
`Cursor cursor =  db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,Constants.COLUMN_YEAR
+ " DESC");`
```

The **null** instead of the String Array of column names equates to **get all columns**.

You could simplify the cursor processing loop by using

```
while (cusror.moveToNext) {

    // do your stuff here
}
cursor.close();
```

**`moveToNext()`** returns false if the cursor is past the last entry (as such this handles an empty cursor).

Comment: ty very much that helped even more @MikeT